# Mongoose deleteMany in pre-hook, how to access all documents that will be deleted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code:

```
postSchema.pre('deleteMany', async function (next: NextFunction) {
  try {
    console.log(this);
    return next(); // normal save
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
});
```

`console.log` is giving a `query` `object`. Are documents available somewhere in the `query`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

query in `deletemany` Located at `_conditions` key of `this`,so you can do like this in Post Model for example :

```
postSchema.pre('deleteMany', async function (next: NextFunction) {
  try {
   let deletedData =await Post.find(this._conditions).lean()
    console.log(deletedData );
    return next(); // normal save
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
});

let Post= mongoose.model("Post", userSchema);
module.exports = Post
```

Comment: +10000 for obscure knowledge reveal

Answer (score 1):

`this.getFilter()` and `this.getUpdate()` are the recommended methods for accessing parameters in the middleware

```
postSchema.pre('deleteMany', async function (next: NextFunction) {
  try {
   let deletedData =await Post.find(this.getFilter()).lean()
    console.log(deletedData );
    next(); // are you sure you want return next() and not next()?
  } catch (error) {
    next(error); // are you sure you want return next(error) and not next(error)?
  }
});

let Post= mongoose.model("Post", userSchema);
module.exports = Post
```

[Link to Mongoose documentation about accessing middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#accessing-parameters-in-middleware)